# Северо-восточный или северовосточный (сложнее, чем можно подумать)

Tags: сложные-слова

Розенталь говорит, что если мы образуем прилагательные из названий частей света, которые являются именами собственными, и если мы используем эти прилагательные как имена нарицательные, то мы пишем их не через дефис, а слитно, и он даёт пример-сравнение такой: *Южно-Уральская железная дорога — южноуральская флора и фауна.*

У меня насчёт моего примера возник вопрос по этому поводу, так как это правило противоречит другому правилу, написанному Розенталём-то: как правильно: *Венец из одуванчиков, собранных на Серево-Востоке, это **северовосточный венец из одуванчиков** или это **северо-восточный венец из одуванчиков**?*

Вопрос этот возник, так как Розенталь говорит, что прилагательные, образованные от названий частиц света, через дефис пишутся. Однако это противоречит, как я уже сказал, его же правилу, которое я в самом-то начале объяснил.

Может быть, это зависит от значения, а именно:

а. венец из одуванчиков, который был собран на серево-востоке где-то, это             **северо-восточный** (через дефис) венец из одуванчиков;

б. венец из одуванчиков, собранный на Северо-Востоке (название части России), это **северовосточный венец из одуванчиков**?

Comment: Вы взяли этот пример из справочника Розенталя?

Answer (score 3):

1. У Розенталя: ***Южно-Уральская железная дорога — южноуральская флора и фауна*** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49 (пункт 14).

***Южный Урал*** – горная система Уральских гор, расположенная на территории России и Казахстана.  ***Южно-Уральская железная дорога*** — имя собственное с дефисным написанием прилагательного.

Нарицательное прилагательное  ***южноуральский*** пишется слитно (образовано на основе сочетания ***Южный Урал***).

2. Пишется через дефис **северо-восток** — направление, часть горизонта между севером и востоком. Дефис сохраняется и в нарицательном прилагательном: ***северо-восточный ветер***.

Есть еще  название региона — ***Северо-Восток России***, включающий несколько областей. Иногда его называют ***Северным Востоком.***

3. Венец из одуванчиков мы соберем ***в регионе Северо-Восток***  (Северный Восток), а не где-то на севере-востоке, поэтому  это будет ***северовосточный венец из одуванчиков.***

А вот ветер у нас северо-восточный. В именах собственных также пишется дефис, например ***Северо-Восточная Сибирь***.